# Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ independent and identically distributed random variables, $X_i \sim U(-\theta, \theta)$ where $\theta > 0$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

*a)* Determine method of moments estimator for $\theta$

*b)* Prove that the estimator found in a) is consistent.

**Solution**

*a)* $\hat{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{3 \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2}{n}}$

but I don't know how to prove *b)*. I couldn't prove that the estimator is asymptotically unbiased. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that unbiasedness is neither necessary nor sufficient for consistency.  For instance, if $X_i$ are iid $ N(\theta,1)$, then $X_1$ is an unbiased but inconsistent estimator for $\theta$. Meanwhile, $\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ is a biased but consistent estimator for $\theta$.

Also, in terms of your updated post, asymptotic unbiasedness doesn't guarantee consistency by the same counterexample above. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280684/intuitive-understanding-of-the-difference-between-consistent-and-asymptotically#:%7E:text=Assuming%20the%20variance%20of%20the,not%20sufficient%20condition%20for%20consistency.) post for more general discussion.

---

Coming to your question, [WLLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and [CMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) immediately tell you that your estimator converges in probability to $\sqrt{3E[X_1^2]}=\theta.$

Comment: I understand what you are saying. At first I forgot to clarify in the post that I want to prove **asymptotic** unbiasedness in order to use the following theorem: $\hat{\theta_n} \rightarrow \theta$ if $E(\hat{\theta_n}) \rightarrow \theta$ and $Var(\hat{\theta_n}) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily to prove $\hat\theta_n$ is unbiased since we know the following theorems.

> Thm 1
> $\hat\theta_n \to \theta$ if $E \hat\theta_n \to \theta$ and $Var\hat\theta_n \to 0$.
>
> Thm 2 $g(\hat\theta_n)\to g(\theta)$ if $\hat\theta_n\to\theta$ and $g(x)$ is continuous.

Then it suffices to prove $E\hat{\theta}^2_n \to \theta^2$ and $Var \hat{\theta}_n^2 \to 0$.

For $E\hat\theta^2_n$,
$$
E\hat\theta^2_n = E \frac{3\sum X_i^2}{n} = 3EX_1^2 = \theta^2
$$

For $Var \hat\theta^2_n$,
$$
Var \hat\theta^2_n = Var \frac{3\sum X_i^2}{n} = \frac9n Var X_1^2 \to 0
$$
as desired.